# How is it that the concatenation of 'pipe', 'dot' and 'dollar' operators, seem to be working in R?

Tags: r, dplyr, magrittr

See the below line of code; **murders** is a dataframe with variables/columns **total**, **population** and **rate**:

```
r <- murders %>% summarize (rate = sum(total) / sum(population) * 10^6) %>% .$rate
```

How is it that the operator `%>%.$` is working in this case? Can someone elaborate?

Edit: I know the result of this line of code(it is extracting the **rate** column), but want to know why or how is it happening because normally, `%>%` is followed by a function, and even if we see `$` operator as a function, it doesn't start JUST after the `%>%` but there is a `.` in between. If we say that the `.` is a placeholder for the output of `%>%` in `$` function, then `%>%$` should also work, because the output of `%>%`, by default and automatically, goes into the first argument of RHS function(which is `$` in our case) and there is no need of `.` in such cases.

Comment: The dot `.` generally represents where the output from the previous function is placed. In this case, it is a `data.frame`, so that is effectively `%>% data.frame(...)$rate`, which should be extracting the `rate` column from the frame returned by the previous step. (And since you say that `murders` is a `data.frame` and not a grouped `tbl_df`, that means that this returns a `numeric` vector, length 1.)

Comment: @r2evans But pipe operator funnels input into the RHS function, and here there is no function on RHS.

Comment: Not true, `$` is a function. It just happens to be a *special* (low-level) function. (If you type in `\`$\`` on the console you'll see `.Primitive("$")`. Which is a function. Just not a very informative description of what kind of function it is.)

Comment: For instance, you can type in `do.call("$", list(mtcars, "cyl"))` which calls the function `"$"` (can be a string or a function literal) with the arguments listed in the second argument `list`. That call is equivalent to `mtcars$cyl`.

Comment: @r2evans Can you please reexplain and elaborate your first comment in a more lucid and less esoteric way? It was a total bouncer to me, thanks.

Comment: Not sure what is esoteric, but I'll try something else: your whole `%>%` pipe here is equivalent to `summarize(murders, rate=sum(total)/sum(population)*10^6)$rate`. So the `.` is being replaced with `summarize(...)`, and the `$` is just regular R, nothing fancy about it. (One huge caveat: `murders %>% summarize(...)$rate` will *not* work.)

Comment: If you first do `tmp <- murders %>% summarize(rate=...)`, and then do `tmp$rate`, that's effectively what `... %>% .$rate` is doing.

Comment: Have you looked at the `magrittr` [Introduction vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/magrittr/vignettes/magrittr.html)? It isn't perfect for this (and does not presume `data.frame`), but it does give a good walk-through on some of the semantics of the `%>%` pipe.

Comment: @r2evans Ok, I now got the point u r trying to make in the first comment, but isn't the 'dot' to be placed inside RHS function? I mean, even if see 'dollar' as a function, the 'dot' is placed even before the start of that, and that is what confused me in the first place. I have never seen a example where there is anything but a function, which appends the 'pipe'. Also, I think u have mistakenly written '%>%', and it just creates confusion, thanks.

Comment: @r2evans If we see A$B as a function of the form $(A, B), and see 'dot' as the place where output of 'pipe' LHS goes as argument, it would make sense, EXCEPT that 'dot' is only meant to be used when the argument is other than 'first', and here it is the first argument. So, just %>%$ should also work, except that it doesn't.

Comment: `$` is *special*. In it's "normal-function" mode (used extremely rarely), it would be seen as `mtxars %>% \`$\`("cyl")`. In that case the dot is not required but can be included, as in `%>% \`$\`(., "cyl")`. Clearer?

Comment: (oops, typo, should have been `mtcars`)

Answer (score 1):

## In this case, it's equivalent to `pull`

### Minimal example

A minimal working example that actually runs is nice to start with.  I recommend providing at least that much in subsequent questions.

```
library(dplyr)
murders <- data.frame('loc'=c('A','B','C'), 
                      'population'=c(10,20,30),
                      'total'=c(2,3,5))

result <- murders %>% 
          summarize (rate = sum(total) / sum(population) * 10^6) %>%
          .$rate

result # 166666.7
```

The `.` in the example above is the [result of the previous pipe](https://magrittr.tidyverse.org/reference/pipe.html).  The dollar sign is an extract operator that is returning the column named rate.

### equivalent example

The `pull` function is getting passed the result of the pipe into the first arg.  Since pull is going to do the same thing as extract (`$`) in this case, it's a bit more explicit in what's going on.

```
result_2 <- murders %>% 
            summarize (rate = sum(total) / sum(population) * 10^6) %>% 
            pull(rate)

result_2 # 166666.7
```

You can illustrate this doing the following

```
result_3 <- murders %>% 
            summarize (rate = sum(total) / sum(population) * 10^6) %>% 
            pull(.data=., var=rate)

result_3 # 166666.7
```

### Pipe to `$` or `[[` will not work

Short story, `$` and `[[` are Primatives, and [magrittr `%>%` works with functions](https://magrittr.tidyverse.org/reference/pipe.html).

> Pipe an object forward into a function or call expression.
>
> lhs %>% rhs
>
> Arguments lhs
>
> A value or the magrittr placeholder. rhs
>
> A function call using the magrittr semantics.

```
`$` # .Primitive("$")
`[[` # .Primative{"[[")
```

The approximate functions `pull` or `getElement` are functions

```
`getElement`
# function (object, name) 
# {
#     if (isS4(object)) 
#         methods::slot(object, name)
#     else object[[name, exact = TRUE]]
# }
# <bytecode: 0x5618b3018358>
# <environment: namespace:base>
```

Comment: "The . in the example above is the result of the previous pipe"

Can you tell me from where did you get this info? Is it in documentation? Can you please share the source article? Because I've searched for the 'dot operator in R' on Google, but couldn't find a thing.

Comment: @HemanthBakaya Sure. The pipe and dot are provided by magrittr. https://magrittr.tidyverse.org/reference/pipe.html

Comment: Ok, I got the point u r trying to make, but isn't the 'dot' to be placed inside the RHS(to the 'pipe') function? I mean, even if we see 'dollar' as a function, the 'dot' is placed even before the start of that, and that is what confused me in the first place. I have never seen a example where there is anything but a function, which appends the 'pipe'.

Comment: If we see A$B as a function of the form $(A, B), and see 'dot' as the place where output of 'pipe' LHS goes as argument, it would make sense, EXCEPT that 'dot' is only meant to be used when the argument is other than 'first', and here it is the first argument. So, just %>%$ should also work, except that it doesn't.

Comment: @HemanthBakaya `%>% $rate` should never work in the same way `%>% [["rate"]]` should never work.  However, `%>% getElement("rate")` should work

Answer (score 1):

### pipes and dollars

the `foo$bar` notation is parsed to be equivalent to  `` `$`(foo, bar) ``, where `$` is a function.

The fact that this function is a primitive has absolutely nothing to do with what is at play here.

Take this example :

```r
df <- data.frame(a=1:2, b = 3:4)
df
#>   a b
#> 1 1 3
#> 2 2 4
```

Because the precedence of the operator `$` is higher than which of `%>%` (see `?Syntax`), the following are equivalent  :

```
df %>% .$a
#> [1] 1 2
df %>% (.$a)
#> [1] 1 2
df %>% `$`(., a)
#> [1] 1 2
```

And in fact *magrittr* cannot even "see" the difference between the former and the latter.

Then because of the semantics of magrittr, and R's syntax for `$`, the following are equivalent:

```
df %>% `$`(., a)
#> [1] 1 2
`$`(df, a)
#> [1] 1 2
df$a
#> [1] 1 2
```

A commenter was surprised that `df %>% $a` doesn't work, the reason is that *magrittr* cannot operate any magic f the syntax is not correct, the parser will choke before any function is called!

This sets us up for the last section though, because `df %>% +1` is correct syntax, so what will *magrittr* do ?

### other operators ?

If we go back to `?syntax` we see that we have other binary operators with higher precedence than `%>%` : `::`, `:::`, `@`, `[` , `[[` and `:`.

We can't use the same trick however with `::` and `:::` (as defined by default) as they use non standard evaluation so *magrittr* wouldn't feed them the proper first argument, but we can have fun with the other ones :

```
3 %>% .:5
#> [1] 3 4 5

df %>% .["a"]
#>   a
#> 1 1
#> 2 2
```

### The special case of `+` and `-`

The `+` and `-` symbols have a particularity, they have a different precedence when used in their unary (`+1`) or binary (`1+2`) form, and the precedence of the unary form is higher than `%>%`.

Because the parser allows the unary form, `df %>% +1` is correct syntax, equivalent to  `` df %>% `+`(1) ``, magrittr then applies its magic on `+` as it would on any function, adding an implicit dot placeholder as the first argument, so the following calls are equivalent :

```
df %>% +1       # unary '+'
df %>% `+`(1)   # unary '+'
df %>% `+(.,1)` # binary '+' !!!
`+`(df,1)       # binary '+' !!!
df + 1          # binary '+' !!!
```

This quirky property can be used if you want to use pipes with *ggplot2* :

```
library(ggplot2)
cars %>%
  ggplot(aes(speed, dist)) +
  geom_point()

# equivalent
cars %>%
  ggplot(aes(speed, dist)) %>%
  +geom_point()
```

The latter call could be piped directly into another function such as `saveRDS()` or `plotly::ggplotly()` while the former couldn't.